# New battery in Asus laptop drops suddenly from 50%

Tags: battery

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and an Asus K55VD Laptop. I bought a NEW battery and I experience this weird behaviour: the battery works fine till approximately 50%, then it suddenly drops to approximately 5% (see the attached picture).

Any workaround? Recalibration? Defected Battery?

[power history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9bGT.png)

Answer (score 0):

I will guess that your new battery is broken or bad quality. Get a replacement if it is under warranty, or buy a new high quality one.